# Extending PHP Session Life

Tags: php, session-cookies

I am in a bit of a twist when it comes to PHP Sessions and the garbage collection it does. I have been trying different methods to extend my sessions to at least 30 days but with no luck. This is the latest piece of code I tried:

```
$one_month=2629746;
session_set_cookie_params($one_month);
if(!isset($_SESSION)) {
    ini_set('session.gc_probability', 0);
    ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime', 60 * 60 * 24 * 7 * 52);
    ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 60 * 60 * 24 * 7 * 52);
    session_start();
}
```

I have searched for a lot of answers about this on stack but none have fixed my issue. I have also spoken to my hosting company in case they had some kind of cron job that automatically deletes session but they said they did not. Funny this code actually works just fine on my local PC but not on my server and I cant seem to find a way to make it work, any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What hosting company is it? I bet it is a restriction on their servers because of security reasons or similar.

Comment: its greengeeks hosting. They have said they do not have any restrictions nor automatic deletion process of the sessions.

Comment: Is it same php version on local machine and on greengeeks?

Comment: What runtime configuration session does it have? https://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php